# Can a Brit Milah double as a Seudah for Purim?

Tags: purim, brit-milah, meal-seudah

Can a Brit Milah, on the morning of Purim, cover you for the Seudah or does it need to be distinct?

Comment: Without knowing whether this concept applies here, it's worth mentioning the concept of *ain me'arvin simcha b'simcha*, we don't usually mix two occasions together. I do not know if this applies to two distinct *seudas mitzvos*.

Comment: ain me'arvin simcha b'simcha is only for weddings no?

Answer (score 3):

Nitei Gavriel ([Purim 70:10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46446&st=&pgnum=387)) says that you can do it the other way. You can make use the Purim Feast for a Pidyon HaBen, Brit, or Bar Mitzvah.

Comment: Is double counting really a unidirectional operation?

Comment: @WAF: I could bring arguments either way. Perhaps a Purim Seuda has to be explicitly made (since it is an explicit mitzvah, as opposed to the others that are generic responses to a happy occasion), and the other celebrations can be tacked on.